# Как исключить все папки в которые вложен файл?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, scss

Нужно найти файлы без нижнего подчёркивания на любом уровне вложенности. Для этого я применяю вот такую маску `src/**/[^_]*.scss` и положить их в `dist/css/`, но мне вместе с файлами прилетают все директории, в которые эти файлы вложены. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исключить все папки выше файлов?

Comment: А чем папки помешали?

Comment: не нужны просто. в папке dist/css  должен лежать файл и больше ни чего. Пример: dist/css/main.css

Comment: Если там должен быть 1 файл, то он там и будет, причём без папок.

Comment: Кажется, должно помочь [gulp-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filenames).